# Can I implement a Base whose Deriveds are automatically calling Base::sanitycheck after Derived::Derived scope?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, c++20

How do I achieve the desired output via suitable modification of any code except `Derived::Derived()`?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
std::ostream& o = std::cout;

struct Base
{
    void sanitycheck() { o << "base checks\n"; }
    Base() { o << "make base\n"; }
};

// Code of struct Derived shall remain unaltered
struct Derived : Base 
{
    Derived() { o << "make derived\n"; }
};

// Dummy might help?
struct Dummy
{
    Base& base;
    Dummy(Base& base) :base(base) {}
    ~Dummy() { base.sanitycheck(); }
};

int main()
{
    Derived x;
    /* desired output:
    make base
    make derived
    base checks     // <-- missing piece
    */
}
```

Background: Base is in a library. Derived is user-supplied. Sanity checks can help mitigate user errors.

Comment: Off topic, but please note that the "alias" `o` for `std::cout` will likely not pass any code-review. It's a bad habit, that doesn't save you as much as you think in typing speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Best you can do is provide a function to create the object:

```
template <std::derived_from<Base> T, typename... Args>
auto make_checked(Args&&... args) -> T {
    T object(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    object.sanitycheck();
    return object;
}

int main(){
    auto x = make_checked<Derived>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aPb35aa3s)

A decent compiler will use [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) so no copy or move is performed. Otherwise, the object will be moved (or copied if it is not movable). You can force the type to be movable if needed:

```
template <std::derived_from<Base> T, typename... Args>
auto make_checked(Args&&... args) -> T requires(std::movable<T>) { ... }
```

Comment: Not perfect, but I am happy to believe that it is "the best one can do" :)